# Clarification of [logic] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Is the [logic](/questions/tagged/logic) tag on SO appropriate for [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134233/iterator-logic-issue-when-creating-new-rmi-chat-server-room/22134273#22134273)?

I've read the tag description; but I'm still not sure if the tag applies to general issues with programming logic (although, that doesn't seem correct, since that's *really* general), or issues specifically related to boolean-centric programs.

Comment: I would say no, that question is mistagged. Better is [tag:loops]? The logic tag is more towards AI-stuff with forward and backward reasoning?

Comment: Hm; maybe. I have a lot of animosity towards the [tag:loops] tag though for reasons I don't fully understand.